# "Till" or "up to" or "to" or another adverb?

Tags: adverbs

Which one is correct?

> 1) "I looked at the photo album till the last photo"
>   2) "I looked at the photo album to the last photo"
>   3) "I looked at the photo album up to the last photo"

Edit: I think the better option is "up to" but "till" seems true to some extent.

Comment: Please tell us which do you think is correct?

Comment: @AIQ I think the better option is "up to" but "till" seems true to some extend.

Comment: That is information that needs to be there in the question. The more details you give, the more likely it is that you will receive good answers. I will edit your question to include that information.